# Five Consecutive days excluding weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a code that raises a flag when number of leaves taken by a person exceeds 5 business days. However, it doesn't raise the flag when we have weekend in middle. Say, someone takes leave on 23,24 and then on 27,28 and 29. As 25 and 26 are weekends, tool doesn't count it. Can someone help me on how i must check the weekend dates here and push the value as "Yes" that includes weekend dates ?

```
function PrepareReport(reportData) {
    var vacationData = [];
    var dayValuesStr = '';
    var dayValuesArray = [];
    if ($("#ddlfromYear").val() == $("#ddltoYear").val()) {
        count = parseInt($("#ddltoMonth").val()) - parseInt($("#ddlfromMonth").val());
    }
    else {
        count = 12 - parseInt($("#ddlfromMonth").val()) + parseInt($("#ddltoMonth").val());
    }
    //val.ResourceID         FullName             EnterpriseID       WorkOrder         Domain Totalhours
    vacationData.push(reportData.FullName);
    vacationData.push(reportData.EnterpriseID);
    vacationData.push(reportData.WorkOrder);
    vacationData.push(reportData.Domain);
    if (reportData.IsOffshore == 1) {
        vacationData.push('Offshore');
    }
    else {
        vacationData.push('Onshore');
    }
    vacationData.push(reportData.TOTALHOURS);
    var counter = 0;
    FlagCounterLastVal = 0;
    vacationData.push("No");
    for (var monthNum = 0; monthNum <= count; monthNum++) {
        dayValuesStr = reportData['MONTH' + monthNum];
        if (dayValuesStr) {

            dayValuesArray = dayValuesStr.split(',');
            var countArray = dayValuesArray.length - 1;
            $.each(dayValuesArray, function (key, val) {
                if (val.endsWith('.00'))//round off values
                {
                    if (parseInt(val) == 0) {
                        vacationData.push('-');
                        counter = 0; // resetting counter to 0 for non-consecutive days
                    }
                    else {
                        if (FlagCounterLastVal > 0) {

                            counter = FlagCounterLastVal;
                        }
                        counter++;
                        vacationData.push(parseInt(val));
                        ****if (counter >= 5 && FlagCounterLastVal == 0) {
                            var index = vacationData.indexOf("No");
                            vacationData[index] = "Yes";
                        }****

                        if (key == (countArray) && count > 0) {  // vacation taken at the month ends
                            FlagCounterLastVal = counter;

                        }
                    }

                }
                else {
                    vacationData.push(val);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return vacationData;
}
```

Comment: Please add your html code, or ideally create a snippet to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getDay](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) for that.

```
var day = yourDateObject.getDay();
var isWeekend = (day === 6) || (day === 0);
```

**6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday**

Comment: Hi Cool JK. I am not sure where to use this getDay function. Can you let me know how to use it in this code?

Comment: Where you want to check weekend just highlight that. because in your code i can not get where i've to add this.

Comment: I have enlcosed it within block letters i.e *. We are checking if counter is greater than 5 there. So, i think we can use getDay() in that part.

Comment: In which field you can store date?

Answer (score 0):

I won't be sharing code here as it's Data Structure and would like you to think a little bit, and try yourself first. If still you won't be able to code it then I will help you out in your code.

What I would do is have 2 arrays, both will be sorted this will help in search. 
1. Having all weekends dates. // weekendArr
2. Leave dates taken by employee. //leaveArr

Steps
1. delete all the weekendArr dates from leaveArr. 
2. Check if leaveArr have continues dates more then 5 or what ever you want it to be.
3. If it is greater then 5 then raise a flag for that employee.

Now you need to decide what data structure you will use to maintain employee leaves, employeeID, and leave flag.

Hope this will be enough to figure out code now.